# How to modify the C Language Program to Print Numbers between -99999,99999 to words

Tags: c, printing, numbers, case

Hello I have a program in C that prints just two digit numbers to words but I have to modify this to make it print numbers between -99999,99999 to words **without** using any loops. I can easily do it by using a loop but I cannot use loops in this case. I am sharing my code for two digit numbers and I'd be glad if you can help me.

```
#include <stdio.h>      // include stdio.h library

int main (void)
{
  int num1, num2;

  printf ("Enter a two-digit number: ");
  scanf ("%1d%1d", &num1, &num2);

  printf ("You have entered: ");

  // print word for the first digit
  switch (num1)
    {
    case 1:
      // special case for numbers between 11-19
      switch (num2)
    {
    case 0:
      printf ("ten");
      return 0;
    case 1:
      printf ("eleven");
      return 0;
    case 2:
      printf ("twelve");
      return 0;
    case 3:
      printf ("thirteen");
      return 0;
    case 4:
      printf ("fourteen");
      return 0;
    case 5:
      printf ("fifteen");
      return 0;
    case 6:
      printf ("sixteen");
      return 0;
    case 7:
      printf ("seventeen");
      return 0;
    case 8:
      printf ("eigthteen");
      return 0;
    case 9:
      printf ("nineteen");
      return 0;
    }
    case 2:
      printf ("twenty");
      break;
    case 3:
      printf ("thirty");
      break;
    case 4:
      printf ("forty");
      break;
    case 5:
      printf ("fifty");
      break;
    case 6:
      printf ("sixty");
      break;
    case 7:
      printf ("seventy");
      break;
    case 8:
      printf ("eighty");
      break;
    case 9:
      printf ("ninety");
      break;
    }

  // print word for the second digit
  switch (num2)
    {
    case 1:
      printf ("-one");
      break;
    case 2:
      printf ("-two");
      break;
    case 3:
      printf ("-three");
      break;
    case 4:
      printf ("-four");
      break;
    case 5:
      printf ("-five");
      break;
    case 6:
      printf ("-six");
      break;
    case 7:
      printf ("-seven");
      break;
    case 8:
      printf ("-eight");
      break;
    case 9:
      printf ("-nine");
      break;
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you make use of recursion?

Comment: @ChrisLoonam Yes sir but I am failing to do so and I am not allowed to use loops so I need to do it with if statements and cases

Comment: Homework assignment?  Divide and conquer!

Comment: You can have up to six characters, including the sign (+|-).  `strlen()` tells you the length of the string.  For all lengths greater the one, there might be a '+' or '-' in the first character, in which case you output "plus" or "minus", I'll let you figure the rest out for yourself.

Comment: So if you are allowed to use recursion (or functions), then this task should teach you to use it. And if you're failing, try again. If you encounter a problem, you are welcome to come back and [edit] your question.